# How do I initiate and show an animation of a div layer?

Tags: angularjs

**Hi guys and gals. I need to open a menu div layer when a button is clicked and close menu div layer if it is open on mouseover event using angular. How do I start with a partially closed div and then get it to open on click event? My code seems sound yet it does not work. Here is the code:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
   <meta name="author" content="" />




   <title>collapsible meny 5</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>

   <style>
   .menu.ng-show {
    animation: my_slide_animation 2s linear;
    }
    @keyframes my_slide_animation {
    from { width:20px; } 
    to { width: 560px; }
    }

    .menu {
    float: right;
    top:80px;
    right: 10px; 
    width:20px;
    height:430px;
    background-color:white;
    border-color:#0AA7E5;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 20px;

    border-radius: 6px 6px;    
    font: bold 12px Verdana; 
    color: red;    
    overflow: none;    
    }


    .button {
     width:260px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:white;
    border-color:#0AA7E5;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-right-width: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px 6px;    
    font: bold 12px Verdana; 
    color: red;   
    } 

    </style>   

    </head>

    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-init="menu">
    <button class="button" ng-mouseover="" ng-click="menu.ng-show"> 
    Contact Us</button>

    <div class="menu" ng-show="menu"></div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
    </script>

     </body>
    </html>
```

**Please enlighten me as to the error in my logic.
Thanks in advance,
Batoe**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following code.

```
 <body ng-app="myApp" >
    <button class="button" ng-mouseover="menu=false" ng-click="menu = !menu"> 
    Contact Us</button>
    <div class="menu" ng-show="menu"></div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngAnimate']);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Please find the working plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/mHiZcj7AiuDB4XIucBqs?p=preview).Is that what u want ?

Comment: Ok, it is a start. but there is no animation from open to close div.

Comment: @Tony Starke Updated the same plunker.Let me know if anything is needed further.

Comment: Outstanding!! How do I set the a default view where the menu is only width: 20px; perhaps a function declaring a default view? or ng init declaring the initial scope menu view?

Comment: Ok, I figured out that you can use a fixed position div layer with a z index of 0 to the sliding div layer z index of 1 to achieve the effect. Thanks a bunch.